# How could have a ListView with a text and RatingBar in each row

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, ratingbar

I have a ListView (or recyclerView) in my activity that each row of it has a text and a RatingBar. I want my program to have the ability of adding and removing Rows, but there is a problem when I remove a row of my ListView, it removes correctly but when I add another text the value of ratingbar in previous row(which deleted) is set to new row I add, what should I do?
the apk :
[enter link description here](http://www.freeuploadsite.com/do.php?id=75791)

here is the code I wrote:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

String[] getstr;
Button btnInsert;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
EditText edtNewName;
TextView txtShow;
ArrayList<String> arrayList;
maxAdapter max;
ListView Lv1;
RatingBar rbExm1;
ImageButton ibtnDelete;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getstr = new String[]{"be alive", "Do your job", "love people"};
    btnInsert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnInsert);
    edtNewName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNewName);
    btnInsert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            addItemFromList();
        }
    });


    arrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(getstr));
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row_xml, R.id.txtExm1, arrayList);

    max = new maxAdapter();
    setListAdapter(max);


    Lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    Lv1.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    edtNewName.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            MainActivity.this.arrayAdapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        }
    });
    Lv1.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3) {

            removeItemFromList(position);
            return true;
        }
    });
    Lv1.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    Lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            try {
                txtShow = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtShow);
                txtShow.setText(max.getItem(position));
                if (max.getItem(position).equals("Navid")){txtShow.setText("Loser");}
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}







// other methods and classes

protected void addItemFromList(){
    max.add(edtNewName.getText().toString());
    edtNewName.setText("");
    max.notifyDataSetChanged();
    max.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
}

protected void removeItemFromList(int position){
    final int DeletePosition = position;
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

    alert.setTitle("Delete");
    alert.setMessage("Do you want to delete item?");
    alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            max.remove(max.getItem(DeletePosition));
            max.notifyDataSetChanged();
            max.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            edtNewName.setText("");
        }
    });
    alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alert.show();

}


private class maxAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    public maxAdapter(){super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row_xml, arrayList);}

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        final int DeletePosition = position;
        View v = convertView;
        if(v == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_xml, parent, false);
        }
        TextView txtExm1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtExm1);
        txtExm1.setText(max.getItem(position));
        ibtnDelete = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.ibtnDelete);
        ibtnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                removeItemFromList(DeletePosition);
            }
        });
        rbExm1 = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.rbExm1);
        rbExm1.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
                fromUser = true;
            }
        });
    return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: The most accurate that I can say is that it seems like your adapter is wrong.

Comment: IMO, your adapter is wrong, or you need 'ViewHolder' object

Comment: I add the code to the first post, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Re initialize the value of the rating bar everytime.

Comment: It dosen't work well because it ruin the whole list, for example I have 7 rows with different values of text and ratingbar, if I delete the row 5, the values of ratingbar 5 places in value of row 6 (which is placed in row 5 now) and ratingbar value of row 6 place in ratingbar value of row 7. I hope you undrestand.
I attach the apk of my program for better understanding